# Split and merge - with DVDs!

Tags: cat

Say I have a large file called `foo.tar.xz`.
I split the file into parts of just under 4.7GB each, using `split -b 4689887232 foo.tar.xz foo.tar.xz.`, which gives me files named `foo.tar.xz.aa`, `foo.tar.xz.ab`, etc.
Then I write each file to a different DVD and send it to Alice using a rather large [homing pigeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_post).

Now Alice could insert each DVD, copy each file to her PC, and then use `cat` and `xz` to get the contents of `foo`: `cat foo.tar.xz.* | tar xfJ -`

Now Assume that Alice has just enough space on her PC to store the extracted contents of `foo`. Is there some flavour of `cat` that will read these files directly from DVDs and pause the stream to allow her to insert the next DVD? Something like `pausecat` or `volumecat`?

Comment: Is re-creating the tarball an option? *I.e.* on your end, do you have the original files, or enough room to extract the tarball?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes

Comment: I was going to suggest using a multi-volume archive, but that doesn’t support seamless compression, so I imagine it wouldn’t be appropriate in this case.

Comment: It may be for some people finding this question. Feel free to write an answer and give some command line examples.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of such a `cat` flavor, but here's a solution which *almost* works:

1. In one terminal run `mkfifo myfifo; tail -c +1 -f myfifo | tar xfJ -`
2. Insert first DVD into DVD-ROM drive (ex. dev/sr0).
3. In a second terminal run `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=myfifo`
4. When `dd` completes, remove the DVD.
5. If you have another DVD, insert into the DVD-ROM drive and go to step 3, else go to step 6.
6. In the first terminal, press CTRL-C to kill `tail` and `tar`.

### How it works

The trick is to use `tail` to continuously read from a named pipe. The output of `tail` is then piped to the command you want to run. Initially the pipe is unopened so nothing happens. But when you begin pumping data into the pipe with `dd`, `tail` picks it up and forwards it to your command.

The magic happens when the flow of data to the pipe stops: `tail` keeps its standard out file descriptor open, which causes your command to pause. Meanwhile, `tail` simply waits for more input.

### The problem

The reason I said it's almost working is because there seems to be a buffering issue which causes `tail` not to write the last bit of data that's fed into it. My hope is that someone can provide the insight to address this.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `catpause` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p 'ready ? ' >&2
do if [ y = "$REPLY" ]
   then cat /dev/dvd 
   fi
done |
tar xJf -
```

It prompts you on `stderr` to reply, and if it is `y` you copy the dvd into a pipe read by the `tar` command. When done enter control-D for end-of-file.